# Progress bar load on every link click

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar

How to make ProgressBar load/appear on every click on link in webview?
currently after click, page is blank for nearly 5 to 7 seconds then ProgessBar appears...

Comment: please add your code

Comment: super.onPageFinished(view, url);
      progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use WebViewClient (see `WebView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient client)`) and override its method

```
onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
```

to start showing your ProgressBar...

E.g.like this:

```
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for doing this is using [WebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html).

### EXAMPLE

```
WebView webView;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview_layout);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_blog);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading);
    lala_icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.lala_icon);

    webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
        }
    });

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    webView.loadUrl(url);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.e("url", url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            Log.e("Loading URL", url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try {
                if (progressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Happy Coding.